# trying to sync random color scripts to be the same random colors for various div tags

Tags: javascript, html, random, colors, synchronization

currently i am using a random color script to generate a background color from a list of hex colors, but i am starting to apply this script to several different divs and would like to sync the colors so they all change to the same color on page load. any advice?

the divs all have different ids. there are some that have the same classes, but some have different classes as well. not sure if this limits my options(?)

below is the script i am currently using below each div tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function ran_col() { //function name
    var color = '#'; // hexadecimal starting symbol
    var letters = ['81ADB5','97C29D','E86A72','F1B36C','A37EA3','277F92']; //Set rotating colors here
    color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * letters.length)];
    document.getElementById('index-blog').style.background = color; // Setting the random color on your div element.
    }
    setTimeout(ran_col,1); // this will run the code immediately
</script>
```

any advice would be greatly appreciated. thank you in advance.

*update:*

I tried adding the script below to the head tag, and it worked on the div id a couple times, but after refreshing the page a few times the div stopped changing color and went blank.

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function ran_col() { //function name
    var color = '#'; // hexadecimal starting symbol
    var letters = ['81ADB5','97C29D','E86A72','F1B36C','A37EA3','277F92']; //Set rotating colors here
    color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * letters.length)];
    document.getElementById('parallelogram').style.background = color; // Setting the random color on your div element.
    }
    setTimeout(ran_col,1); // this will run the code immediately
</script>
```

any advice?

i also tried using `getElementbyClass` but that also did not work. any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Everytime you call Math.random(), you are generating a new value so  the color value will be different for each div. Try setting the value of color in the head section of the document and then applying it to the divs.  This way the color will be same for all of them.

Comment: thank you for the speedy reply @DennisPriebe! any chance you would be able to give an example of the code that would go in the header? i'm new to javascript, so it would feel like to trying to invent the light bulb for me to trial and error on my own. i've been looking at other threads and articles to see if i can find something like this, but i'm not finding what i need to learn.